Mac window tiling icons & keyboard shortcuts
Window tiling is now available in macOS Sequoia 15. I was happily using rectangle, and wished to give a try to this native solution (sorry, rectangle developers!).
Apple's website gives the window tiling icons & keyboard shortcuts at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl9674d0b0/15.0/mac/15.0 but except for full-screen, this seems to be inoperative...

Is this the same for you, dear community ?

All those keyboard shortcuts work here.

maybe related to my language setting (french) - I will explore more

I had misred the instructions and was trying to use the Command key instead of the (less used) Fn key.
It is not conveniently placed on a numeric keyboard, such that I chose to remap the caps-lock key to that fn key in the "customize modifier key" section from system preferences:


I still do not know how to apply this to iTerm2 which somewhere uses different keyboard shortcuts. Any help appreciated :-)
